B2C Custom Policy: Error changing localAccountPasswordReset Content selfAsserted policy version beyond 1.1.0
Why can't I update the LocalAccountPasswordReset selfAsserted version beyond 1.1.0?
For a related issue, I am attempting to update the localAccountPasswordReset Content Definition to a later version.  However whenever I do so I get an error 'The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred'.  It seems any version of `selfAsserted' beyond 1.1.0 (such as 1.2.0, 2.1.7, 2.1.30) is invalid.  I can confirm a newer version works for on other tenants and for the sign in/sign up pages.

Technical Profile

Orchestration Steps, SubJourney PasswordReset

UserJourney CustomSignUpSignIn, OrchestrationStep 3


For the linked question you've shared the content definition and technical profile, but what does the orchestration step that executes the technical profile look like?

@DaveD I made a number of changes to the related issue to show all configuration from the User Journey to the Content Definition.

Are those the actual working custom policies? Asking as your PasswordReset subjourney appears to be defined as a UserJourney rather than a SubJourney, even though it's being called as a SubJourney.

@DaveD Thanks for the edit.  I believe they are, I confirmed the 'PasswordReset'   lives inside  .  You are saying this should cause the Policy to break?  I confirmed looking at the URL that I am looking at the correct Custom Policies. (URL: .../B2C_1A_signup_signin_EcoSystemssaml/api/CombinedSigninAndSignup/unified?claimsexchange=ForgotPasswordExchange...  Policy inheritance: B2C_1A_signup_signin_EcoSystemssaml > B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensionsWMSMAL > B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBaseWMSMAL)

I can't even upload a policy that references a UserJourney as a SubJourney. Do you also have a SubJourney defined with the id PasswordReset?

You are correct @DavidD, I have updated the OP.

I can see from your Data URI urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:selfasserted:1.1.0 that you are using the old Data URI values and these no longer work.
You need to migrate the page layouts to the new Data URI values which contain the word contract
urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:selfasserted:1.1.0 becomes urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.33
Note, the latest documented Self Asserted page layout version is 2.1.30 but 2.1.33 is the latest published version.


Thanks! I copied this answer to my other post but credited you @bolt-io.
